# Unable to update ubuntu 14.04 LTS by using 'sudo apt-get update'

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-sources

When I'm trying to update ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I got this error message:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (dist)  
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

[image: screenshot]

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`:

```
deb download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 2):

just add

> http://

edit it like this `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib non-free`

then `sudo apt-get update` and if that doesn't fix which it should then just delete the file from the sources.list.d directory dont worry it wont effect anything.

Comment: if i was able to help give a vote or pick as answer so other can get help easily to find it as a solution.